# replace line feed char(10) in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have some data coming in from my DB (SQL Server 2008) and it has been formatted with char(10) as the line feeds and I want to replace them on my iOS device with \n.

How would I search for the char(10)?  I know I would do replaceOccurancesOfStringWith but I need to nail this character down.

Comment: Do you want to replace literally with \n (that being a backslash and the character n) or just by \n the line end character? As \n the line end character has the numeral representation 10 they would already be the same.

Comment: hah, good point - makes my answer look a bit silly now :(

Comment: What does "nail this character down" mean? What is it you are asking?

Comment: my text is showing up all on the same line so somewhere the is a disconnect.  I checked and in my string in my database I can check for the char(10)'s and they are where they should be but they are not displaying in my app.  So I assumed for some reason I needed to do some conversion.

Comment: So your question should be __'how can I stop my text all appearing on one line'__

Comment: How are you displaying the strings?

Comment: I am displaying the strings in a UITextView

Answer (score 1):

Make an NSString to replace using `stringWithCString:encoding:`, something like

```
// Make the string to find
char str[2] = { 10, 0 };
NSString *toFind = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Now do your replace :)
NSSTring *out = [input stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:toFind withString:@"\\n"];
```

Comment: thanks for the help, not working  - something must be stripping this out before it get to my app because this is not working.

Comment: It might be working - your problem is probably somewhere else entirely. Edit your question and add how you are displaying the text and some example text that's not displaying correctly.